# Сортировка внутри JOIN'a

Tags: mysql, join

Есть две простые таблицы:

Товары и остатки этих товаров

Товары имеют поля: **id, name**

Остатки имеют поля: **id, product_id, price**

Соотвественно 1 товар имеет много остатков по полю **product_id**

Хочу получить самый дешевый товар. Делаю запрос:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Products AS p
JOIN Balance AS b ON p.id = b.product_id
GROUP BY
    b.product_id
```

Проблема в том, что **JOIN** из-за группировки берет самую **первую** запись остатка.
Т.е. перед присоединением надо както отсортировать таблицу остатков по полю **price**. Но вот что то ума не хватает, куда запихнуть эту сортировку.

Comment: вложенные селекты знакомы?

Comment: Да, знакомы, но думал обойтись именно JOIN'ом

Answer (score 1):

Хоть MySQL и допускает такую вольность (при дефолтовых настройках), это не имеет смысла. Никогда не делайте так: `SELECT * … GROUP BY`. По стандарту SQL во фразе SELECT могут упоминаться только те поля по которым группируете и агрегатные функции от других полей.
Правильный запрос:

```
SELECT product_id, MIN(price)
FROM Balance
GROUP BY product_id
```

Теперь, если хотите дополнить результат полями из Products, оформляете как подзапрос:

```
SELECT p.*, b.price
FROM
  Products AS p JOIN
  (
    SELECT product_id, MIN(price) AS price
    FROM Balance
    GROUP BY product_id
  ) AS b ON b.product_id=p.id
```

Comment: Я тоже слышал, что знак * не очень правильно. Но на небольших и недорогих проектах это приходится делать для ускорения процесса :) Хотя, честно я так и не понял, почему нельзя *

Comment: Хотите быстро получить непонятный результат? Нельзя потому, что это бессмыслица. Просто поверьте, а поймете потом. Авторитеты БД не зря ввели это правило. Только MySQL "отличился", да и то, зависит от настроек сервера. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: Спасибо! Будем читать :)